# Create Multiple JSON files from Dataframe R

Tags: json, r

I have a dataframe and I want to create individual JSON files and use one of the column names to name each of the JSON files.

The following code will create multiple CSV files, but instead I want JSON.
I am using the iris dataset from plyr.

```
library(plyr)
d_ply(iris, .(Species), function(x) write.csv(x, file = paste(unique(x$Species), ".csv", sep = "")))
```

Comment: There are many packages that handle JSON in R: `jsonlite`, `RJSONIO`, `rjson` and others.

Comment: iris isn't from `plyr`

Comment: `apply(iris, 2, jsonlite::toJSON)` will give you JSON for each column.

Answer (score 1):

As Nicola suggests, there are many packages for producing JSON. Adapting your `d_ply` code:

```
library(jsonlite)
d_ply(iris, .(Species), function(x) {
    writeLines(toJSON(x), file = paste0(x$Species[1], ".json"))
})
```